# Tomoyo profile doesnt exist

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I have installed on my Vbox Parrot-Security 32bit
After a day, I got error while booting machine.

```
/dev/sda1: clean, 450934/1523712 files 3510770/6092032 blocks
I got :
TOMOYO: Default profile doesn't exist.
TOMOYO: Select a profile from the following list.
```

After this its looks it want input but when i type help, ? , /? , --help, -h its says:

```
TOMOYO: Select a profile from the following list.
disable
```

Anyone know what happened and how I can fix this?

I bypassed this by presing 'e' in GNU GRUB and in line which starts with linux i changed (ro initrd=/install/...) with rw init=/bin/bash (run this with ctrl-x)and when shell starts I run exec /sbin/init.

I saw in boot editor in linie linux ... there is: 
security=tomoyo i could change that or no?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: sorry i cant use here off-topic but i wann do that but there is limitation

Answer (score 0):

when you boot parrot you will see error type this:

1- disable

2- sudo apt install parrot-core

3- sudo apt autoremove

4- sudo apt autoclean

5- sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade

6- sudo reboot

after rebooting you will be a little bit confused because you will notice some changes in terminal fonts and some icons, etc..
Don't worry this an update and we all got it after updating Parrot.